# Deserialize multiple level object JSON

Tags: apex, json, callout, deserialize, google

So I am working with Google calendar data in the following format:

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#events",
 "etag": "\"thEtag\"",
 "summary": "samuel.reyes@genko.com",
 "updated": "2018-08-20T18:11:13.081Z",
 "timeZone": "America/Denver",
 "accessRole": "reader",
 "defaultReminders": [],
 "nextSyncToken": "randomblahblah",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"etag\"",
   "id": "7q7r94v1vjoa72tq63kee",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=N3E3cjk0djF",
   "created": "2018-03-01T16:28:26.000Z",
   "updated": "2018-03-01T18:27:01.967Z",
   "summary": "Isolated Work Time - Not Available (Quiet Time)",
   "creator": {
    "email": "samuel.reyes@genko.com",
    "self": true
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "samuel.reyes@genko.com",
    "self": true
   },
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2018-02-26T10:00:00-07:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Denver"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2018-02-26T12:00:00-07:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Denver"
   },
   "recurrence": [
    "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR"
   ],
   "iCalUID": "123455@google.com",
   "sequence": 0,
   "reminders": {
    "useDefault": true
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"etag\"",
   "id": "eventid",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MmU4OGkxNTJmaG",
   "created": "2018-07-20T15:45:23.000Z",
   "updated": "2018-07-27T15:41:36.966Z",
   "summary": "Joe / Samuel",
   "creator": {
    "email": "joe@genko.com"
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "joe@genko.com"
   },
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2018-07-26T13:30:00-06:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Denver"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2018-07-26T14:00:00-06:00",
    "timeZone": "America/Denver"
   },
   "recurrence": [
    "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=2;BYDAY=TH"
   ],
   "iCalUID": "2e88i152@google.com",
   "sequence": 0,
   "attendees": [
    {
     "email": "joe@genko.com",
     "organizer": true,
     "responseStatus": "accepted"
    },
    {
     "email": "samuel.reyes@genko.com",
     "self": true,
     "responseStatus": "needsAction"
    }
   ],
   "reminders": {
    "useDefault": true
   }
  }
}, etc.... untold numbered list of such events
```

I have tried deserializing them into a normal Map like follows:

```
`Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(items);`
```

And it works fine for everything but `items`. Items just ends up as one long value with `items` as the key. And I am sure it's probably not overly complicated, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to get the `items` sub-object to also deserialize into some kind of usable List. To make things even more complicated, the sub-object has it's own small number of subobjects....

I went and tried to create a object structure like follows, but I don't think I've done it right, and am not figuring out how to properly deserialize it into more or less this format.

```
public class GoogleCalendar{
    public String kind;
    public String etag;
    public Datetime updated_date;
    public String timezone;
    public String accessRole;
    public String nextSyncToken;
    public List<GoogleCalendarItems> gcitems;
}
public class GoogleCalendarItems{
    public String index_number;
    public String kind;
    public String etag;
    public String event_id;
    public String event_status;
    public String htmlLink;
    public String created_date;
    public String updated_date;
    public String iCalUID;
    public String sequence;
    public GCI_creator creator;
    public GCI_organizer organizer;
    public ItemReminders itemReminders;
    public GCI_recurrence recurrence;
    public GCI_start start_time;
    public GCI_end end_time;
}

private class GCI_end{
    public Datetime end_time;
}
private class GCI_start{
    public Datetime start_time;
}
private class GCI_recurrence{
    public String RRULE;
}
private class ItemReminders{
    public Boolean useDefault;
}
private class GCI_organizer{
    public String organizer_email;
}
private class GCI_creator{
    public String creator_email;
}
```

At this point I am really tempted just to build a Nodejs application/API on Firebase, and parse the Google Calendar JSON into something usuable, and returning that to Salesforce....

I could really use some help! Even if it's just a couple of people saying "Yeah, you should probably do the Firebase route with this one..." Please/Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## deserializeUntyped

You probably misinterpreted the data. You should have had a `List<Object>`, which in turn would have been a series of `Map<String, Object>`, etc. If you just "debug" it, it all gets squished back down into a string.

## deserialize (with class)

This failed because you didn't match up the names of the fields correctly. For example, items/0/creator/email should have been just `email`, not `creator_email`. The name must be correct all the way down.

## JSON2apex (a.k.a. EZ mode)

Using [json2apex](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/), you can get a parser all built for you, and then you just:

```
GoogleJsonWrapper wrapper = GoogleJsonWrapper.parse(jsonSource);
```

Here's what that output looks like. Feel free to make your own version (it also comes with a unit test!).

---

```
//
// Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
//
// The supplied json has fields with names that are not valid in apex
// and so can only be parsed with explicitly generated code, this option
// was auto selected for you.

public class GoogleJsonWrapper {

    public class Reminders {
        public Boolean useDefault {get;set;} 

        public Reminders(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'useDefault') {
                            useDefault = parser.getBooleanValue();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Reminders consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public String kind {get;set;} 
    public String etag {get;set;} 
    public String summary {get;set;} 
    public String updated {get;set;} 
    public String timeZone {get;set;} 
    public String accessRole {get;set;} 
    public List<DefaultReminders> defaultReminders {get;set;} 
    public String nextSyncToken {get;set;} 
    public List<Items> items {get;set;} 

    public GoogleJsonWrapper(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'kind') {
                        kind = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'etag') {
                        etag = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'summary') {
                        summary = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'updated') {
                        updated = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'timeZone') {
                        timeZone = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'accessRole') {
                        accessRole = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'defaultReminders') {
                        defaultReminders = arrayOfDefaultReminders(parser);
                    } else if (text == 'nextSyncToken') {
                        nextSyncToken = parser.getText();
                    } else if (text == 'items') {
                        items = arrayOfItems(parser);
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'GoogleJsonWrapper consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public class Start {
        public String dateTime {get;set;} 
        public String timeZone {get;set;} 

        public Start(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'dateTime') {
                            dateTime = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'timeZone') {
                            timeZone = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Start consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public class Creator_Z {
        public String email {get;set;} 

        public Creator_Z(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'email') {
                            email = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Creator_Z consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public class Attendees {
        public String email {get;set;} 
        public Boolean organizer {get;set;} 
        public String responseStatus {get;set;} 
        public Boolean self {get;set;} 

        public Attendees(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'email') {
                            email = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'organizer') {
                            organizer = parser.getBooleanValue();
                        } else if (text == 'responseStatus') {
                            responseStatus = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'self') {
                            self = parser.getBooleanValue();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Attendees consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public class DefaultReminders {

        public DefaultReminders(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'DefaultReminders consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public class Items {
        public String kind {get;set;} 
        public String etag {get;set;} 
        public String id {get;set;} 
        public String status {get;set;} 
        public String htmlLink {get;set;} 
        public String created {get;set;} 
        public String updated {get;set;} 
        public String summary {get;set;} 
        public Creator creator {get;set;} 
        public Creator organizer {get;set;} 
        public Start start {get;set;} 
        public Start end_Z {get;set;} // in json: end
        public List<String> recurrence {get;set;} 
        public String iCalUID {get;set;} 
        public Integer sequence {get;set;} 
        public Reminders reminders {get;set;} 
        public List<Attendees> attendees {get;set;} 

        public Items(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'kind') {
                            kind = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'etag') {
                            etag = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'id') {
                            id = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'status') {
                            status = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'htmlLink') {
                            htmlLink = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'created') {
                            created = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'updated') {
                            updated = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'summary') {
                            summary = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'creator') {
                            creator = new Creator(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'organizer') {
                            organizer = new Creator(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'start') {
                            start = new Start(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'end') {
                            end_Z = new Start(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'recurrence') {
                            recurrence = arrayOfString(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'iCalUID') {
                            iCalUID = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'sequence') {
                            sequence = parser.getIntegerValue();
                        } else if (text == 'reminders') {
                            reminders = new Reminders(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'attendees') {
                            attendees = arrayOfAttendees(parser);
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Items consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public class Creator {
        public String email {get;set;} 
        public Boolean self {get;set;} 

        public Creator(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'email') {
                            email = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'self') {
                            self = parser.getBooleanValue();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Creator consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    public static GoogleJsonWrapper parse(String json) {
        System.JSONParser parser = System.JSON.createParser(json);
        return new GoogleJsonWrapper(parser);
    }
    
    public static void consumeObject(System.JSONParser parser) {
        Integer depth = 0;
        do {
            System.JSONToken curr = parser.getCurrentToken();
            if (curr == System.JSONToken.START_OBJECT || 
                curr == System.JSONToken.START_ARRAY) {
                depth++;
            } else if (curr == System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT ||
                curr == System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
                depth--;
            }
        } while (depth > 0 && parser.nextToken() != null);
    }
    






    private static List<String> arrayOfString(System.JSONParser p) {
        List<String> res = new List<String>();
        if (p.getCurrentToken() == null) p.nextToken();
        while (p.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
            res.add(p.getText());
        }
        return res;
    }



    private static List<Items> arrayOfItems(System.JSONParser p) {
        List<Items> res = new List<Items>();
        if (p.getCurrentToken() == null) p.nextToken();
        while (p.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
            res.add(new Items(p));
        }
        return res;
    }



    private static List<DefaultReminders> arrayOfDefaultReminders(System.JSONParser p) {
        List<DefaultReminders> res = new List<DefaultReminders>();
        if (p.getCurrentToken() == null) p.nextToken();
        while (p.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
            res.add(new DefaultReminders(p));
        }
        return res;
    }





    private static List<Attendees> arrayOfAttendees(System.JSONParser p) {
        List<Attendees> res = new List<Attendees>();
        if (p.getCurrentToken() == null) p.nextToken();
        while (p.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
            res.add(new Attendees(p));
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is super helpful. Thanks a lot! The explanations make sense, and the website you linked is very helpful. I think with the information you've provided I should be on track to get this figured out. Thanks!